# Application not finding configuration file at system startup

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-10

I am developing a simple Wpf application with C # that has been configured to boot with the operating system.

```
public static void RegisterProgram()
    {
        try
        {
            RegistryKey reg = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
            reg.SetValue("Screenshot Teamviewer", System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Register Key: "+ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

This system creates an .xml configuration file that must be used to execute some commands at the time of the operating system boot. In the debug tests everything goes perfectly well, but when I go to practice the application is not working as it should. It just doesn't find the data file and it just doesn't work automatically. after booting, if i open the installed program manually, everything goes well.
I have already checked the program folder and its executable in the exceptions of my ativirus, but even so it is not working.
Another attempt was to create a Thread to wait for the operating system to start up completely, and then start the process, but even so, nothing works as desired.

My data file for the application is here.
[image]

This is the code that checks for the file's existence.

```
public static bool ExistArchice()
    {
        try
        {
            var directory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            var path = Path.Combine(directory, "configuration.xml");
            bool IsExist = File.Exists(path);
            int count = 0;

            while (!IsExist)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(10000);

                IsExist = File.Exists(path);

                if (count >= 50)
                    break;

                count++;
            }
            return File.Exists(path);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw new Exception("Exist Archice: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

This is the read code for the file.

```
public static Configuration ReaderXml()
    {
        try
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Configuration));
            var directory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            var path = Path.Combine(directory, "configuration.xml");
            StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(path);
            Configuration configuration = (Configuration)serializer.Deserialize(streamReader);
            return configuration;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw new Exception("Reader Xml: "+ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

These two methods are not being able to find the configuration.xml file, when the program is started together with the system.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you need to step through this code if you can. If you are in an environment where you can attatch the debugger, try adding code to wait for 30 or 60 seconds, long enough for you to open Visual Studio and attatch. If that doesn't work, try keeping a log file with the values of variables and see how far the code actually gets and what lines get run. That should help give us more information on what's going wrong.

Comment: For testing purposes only: try hard-coding the full location of the configuration file. If it works, I suspect that the _working directory_  of the application is not what you expect. In that case, you probably want to change the code to look for the directory the .exe is in rather than using the working directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research on the internet I ended up exchanging a specific line of code and everything worked fine.
Basically I switched this line:

```
var directory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
```

By this line:

```
var c = Path.GetDirectoryName(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString());
```

What happened in the first code is that it looked for a path that was not the root of my program, something like (C: \ Windows \ System32).
The second code takes the correct path from where my information .xml file is.
I thank everyone for their suggestions, they were very helpful.
Thank you!